# Is there a way to configure SQL server 2000 (or 2008) to accept 'sa' connections only from the local subnet?

Tags: sql-server

I want to tighten security by forbidding 'sa' logins unless they're from the local subnet. Is there a way to list somewhere the acceptable subnets certain users can connect from in SQL server 2000 or SQL server 2008?

Thanks!

Isaac

Answer (score 2):

In SQL 2008, you can use logon triggers.  Read all about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx).